# Call Jasmine Test with different Objects

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a bunch of services, like:

```
function ServiceA() {}
ServiceA.name = "Service A";
ServiceA.description = "A service called A";

ServiceA.doStuff = new function(inputString){...});
```

that:

1. all must have the same properties set (name, description)
2. all have a method with the same name, but the methods content is different for each service.

Currently I have a seperate test for each service, checking the properties and method result. But as the tests/things to test are identical for each service, I wonder if i can do something like this:

```
   var services = [ServiceA, ServiceB, ServiceC];
   for (index = 0; index < services.length; index++) {
      describe("Testing Service", testFunction(services[index]));
   }

   function testFunction(service){
      it("bla", function(){...}
   }
```

I'm using Karma with Jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get what I want like this:

```
var allServices = [
    { service: ServiceA, expectedResult: "resultA"},
    { service: ServiceB, expectedResult: "resultB"},
    { service: ServiceC, expectedResult: "resultC"}
];

for (index = 0; index < allServices.length; index++) {
    var service2test = allServices[index].service;
    var expectedResult= allServices[index].expectedResult;

    describe("Testing Service", function() {
    ... 
    //test properties of service2test
    //compare return value of service2test with expectedResult
    ... 
    });
}
```

Making a separate test function and passing the service to it didn't work because of the following error:

> cannot read property call of undefined